# How can the US prevent Russia from deploying nukes in orbit/space without starting WW3?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, nuclear-weapons, space

NYT [reported](https://www.nytimes.com/2024/02/14/us/politics/intelligence-russia-nuclear.html) on Feb 14:

> Officials said that the new intelligence, which they did not describe in detail, raised serious questions about whether Russia was preparing to abandon the Outer Space Treaty of 1967, which bans all orbital nuclear weapons. But since Russia does not appear close to deploying the weapon, they said, it is not considered an urgent threat. [...]
>
> ABC News reported earlier that the intelligence had to do with Russian space-based antisatellite nuclear weaponry. Current and former officials said that the launch of the antisatellite did not appear imminent, but that there was a limited window of time, which they did not define, **to prevent its deployment**.

Short of shooting it down (or destroying it on the ground, before launch) and possibly thus starting WW3, how can the US prevent the deployment of a such a weapon in orbit/space by Russia? It's not like they've been particularly sensitive to [economic] sanctions, thus far.

N.B.: (aside confusing press reports on the exact nature of the weapon) the [answer](https://www.politico.com/news/2024/02/20/biden-white-house-russia-space-weapon-00142172) from administration officials is that they were conducting secret negotiations to convince Russia not to *test* the weapon.
These efforts reportedly involved trying to convince China and India to  support the US in this. And now the blame game is on that public disclosure has scuppered these.

Comment: Voting to close: As my answer shows, this question will only invite speculations due to the lack of information available. Let's just wait till more information is available before allowing questions on this subject.

Comment: @sfxedit If you don't believe a question is answerable without vague speculation, its best not to answer it.

Comment: @LioElbammalf Sometimes its only after you write a draft of an answer that you realise that its more speculative than reasonably factual.

Comment: Russia (or the USA or the UK or PRC for what matters) could start WW3 at any moment, for any reason. So there is no "hard rule" about what other players can or can not do in order to prevent it.

Comment: This question is also borderline too technical. If it was a political question one could probably generalize to "how do you in general negotiate issues with an unfriendly nation" or "how do arms control treaties get negotiated", which could be answered instead of technical/military solutions, which would be less ontopic here.

Comment: +1 and voting to reopen this question, for two reasons. First, one can't tell if the question cannot be verified with sources available to the public before asking it. If it's not possible, then that's still an answer. Second, if sources become available to the public (it certainly looks like it will be the case for this topic), then the question becomes answerable.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution: the prevention talk reminded me of the Cuban missile crisis. While the US had some means (naval embargo) to prevent some stuff getting to Cuba, the Soviets didn't have an equivalent in preventing stuff (Jupiter missiles) from getting to Turkey. It's not clear what the equivalent of naval embargo of space would look like. So discussing the feasible space of options for politicians seems on-topic enough to me but, YMMV.

Comment: @Fizz That's why I said borderline. If it becomes too technical (like "you have to use the new hyperdrive-antigraviton technology in order to stop them") then this is the wrong place for that in my opinion. We could just take the current state of the art and ask for political implications maybe, which might be very speculative (WW3 or no WW3 - that is the question) because nothing happened yet. This question might simply be 1-5 years ahead of its time which doesn't mean that it's a bad question, just one that cannot be answered in a good way now.

Comment: Give Russia something it likes more than WW3, and keep giving it, so it won't choose to give up receiving that thing just for the sake of WW3.

Comment: Sorry, this seems like a push question.  Technically a "deployment" in space is a launch of a nuclear missile.  So the act of a launch itself would be starting a nuclear war.  The premise that preventing a launch of a nuclear missile is the starting of a nuclear war, rather than an act of preventing such a war, smacks of a push question.  If you insist that you don't mean it that way, I am tempted to believe that.  But it is what's written here.  The question's premise is assigning the blame rather than just supporting an inquiry.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Develop equally capable system and then sign a treaty that neither side will deploy.

This will not work if the system developed by USA would be significantly inferior. Ideally the counterweight system should be better.

This is exactly how the Cold War worked.

Comment: Yeah, and there's also the matter of time frame and incentives. Russia may care less about their own satellites than e.g. threatening starlink, which is hard to do with conventional weapons due to the number of sats involved. OTOH nukes in orbit could serve as mass EMP. Of course, we don't know exactly how Russia plans to use this (if the limited intel published is even correct).

Comment: FWTW, Soloviev has been [fantasizing](https://youtu.be/ACOqIjASvgI?t=46) about Russia taking out Starlink with nukes, but of course whether he has any real clue about the real intent of his master is anybody's guess.

Comment: This is exactly how the Cold War worked.

Answer (score 1):

All the media reports are currently speculating and there isn't any verifiable public data available on this subject. For all we know, it could just be:

1. The American establishment creating anti-Russian hype for domestic politics (to try and push the Republicans to support aid for Ukraine and / or an attempt by Republicans to [block surveillance reforms](https://www.wired.com/story/section-702-privacy-reforms-sabotage-campaign/)).  (OR)

2. The Russians trying to rattle US / NATO to prevent more sanctions and bring them to the negotiating table.

If we assume the media reports are right, consider the two scenarios mentioned:

1. Russia plans to launch orbital nuclear weapons.
2. Russia plans to launch satellite weaponry capable of shooting down missiles and / or other satellites.

The *Outer Space Treaty* (OST) clearly prohibits putting nuclear weapons in space, and doing so would earn worldwide condemnation for Russia.

> The treaty's key arms control provisions are in Article IV. States-parties commit not to:
>
> - Place in orbit around the Earth or other celestial bodies any nuclear weapons or objects carrying WMD.
> - Install WMD on celestial bodies or station WMD in outer space in any other manner.
> - Establish military bases or installations, test "any type of weapons," or conduct military exercises on the moon and other celestial bodies.

In such a situation, the US and its allies could manage to create enough support to impose North Korean level sanction on Russia. Even Russian allies like China or India would be forced to (partially) support it because if Russia puts WMDs in space, US / NATO will too. That would threaten the Chinese too. If China does it, India will be forced to so too - so there will be domino effect worldwide. But neither China nor India would like to divert their precious economic resource for such a thing (to get into race on who can put more "WMD in space" war). Russia already knows how the failure to manage its economy had contributed to the breaking up of its country (the USSR) once. And really effective sanctions - with both the west and the east jointly imposing it - would be devastating for it.

The second plan is however more difficult to thwart as the OST doesn't ban *conventional weapons* in space. In fact, in 1974, the USSR had already secretly launched a satellite with a self-defence gun that fired in orbit:

[image: Photo: Russian Almaz Space Cannon]

([Soviet Almaz Space Cannon](https://twitter.com/RussianSpaceWeb/status/1359529592327991297))

Depending on how desperate the US is to thwart such a scenario today, without military force, the US would have to rely more on "carrots" than "sticks". The "carrots" to entice Russia to abandon this plan could include:

1. Agree not to expand NATO, in writing.
2. Agree not to seize Russian sovereign assets and funds in the west, and / or unfreeze them.
3. Open negotiations again on the missile and nuclear weapons treaties that US / NATO has backed out of and abandoned.
4. Agree to partially lift sanctions and resume oil or gas trade with Europe.

The "stick" could include:

1. Threatening to seize Russian sovereign assets and funds in the west and giving some of it to Ukraine.

However, actually doing so would result in a complete breakdown of relationship between Russia and the west, and even invite repercussion for the US, worldwide, as most countries (even US allies) would no longer trust the US with their funds. It would also undermine the US dollar completely. That is why I believe that the US would have to rely on "carrots" only approach for this scenario.

With its own "defensive" Space Force under the Pentagon, the United States also has no moral stand to object to Russia's own plans to militarise space. Thus, this is also likely to hamper its ability to win international support against Russia's action (which it too is likely to claim is for its "defence"). Without non-western support from the "Global South", any condemnation and sanction would just be weak and ineffective.

Note also that the US and Russia interpret the provisions of OST differently:

> For example, the United States and Russia disagree on the meaning of the “peaceful purposes” upon which the OST is premised. The United States interprets peaceful purposes broadly as “non-aggressive,” and Russia interprets peaceful purposes narrowly as “non-military.”[17] The United States’ interpretation is in agreement with Article IV of the OST, which expressly condones the use of military personnel for peaceful purposes.[18] Because there is no international consensus on the meaning of peaceful purposes, each state conducts their affairs in accordance with their own sometimes conflicting national interpretations.[19] Several problems follow from the uncertainty. For example, dual-use technology like satellites are not prohibited by the OST because they have a legitimate–albeit nonexclusive–peaceful purpose.[20] Destruction of satellites is similarly unprotected.[21] Because the use of military personnel for peaceful purposes is allowed under the OST,[22] and the United States’ interpretation of peaceful purposes does not exclude military activity, the Space Force is arguably legal under international law.

**References**:

1. [Leak of Russian ‘Threat’ Part of a Bid to Kill US Surveillance Reform, Sources Say](https://www.wired.com/story/section-702-privacy-reforms-sabotage-campaign/)
2. [The Outer Space Treaty at a Glance](https://www.armscontrol.org/factsheets/outerspace)
3. [Salyut-3 (Almaz OPS-2) space station](https://www.russianspaceweb.com/almaz_ops2.html)
4. [Does the U.S. Space Force Violate the Outer Space Treaty?](https://djilp.org/does-the-u-s-space-force-violate-the-outer-space-treaty/)

Comment: None of these look like a credible prevention plan to me. To get NK style sanctions you'd need incontrovertible proof, which seems hard to get for something that's not even deployed yet, and probably not easy to do even later--weapon inspections in space (e.g. if it's also boobytrapped.) Second part slightly more plausible that the US could negotiate some secret deal, but your scenario which amounts to "US gives Russia everything they want" sounds equally fanciful.

Comment: And why did you answer the Q, especially at such length, if you also voted to close it?

Comment: And news is also that Russia [denied](https://www.reuters.com/world/kremlin-dismisses-us-warning-about-russian-nuclear-capability-space-2024-02-15/) they are working on this, so that makes it harder for any kind of world-wide sanctions or public negotiations.

Comment: @Fizz *None of these look like a credible prevention plan to me.* That depends on how much you believe in the propaganda that the Russians are irrational. Look at the the many treaties that were signed between the two powers during and after the cold war to limit their WMDs - Americans think long-term and are very pragmatic and practical when they know that the balance has tipped and is not in their favour. If they believe Russia has better space weapons technology than them, they will *temporarily* concede some favours to Russia till they can attain parity with them.

Comment: @Fizz As I mentioned elsewhere, sometimes it's only after you write a draft or two of an answer that you realise that the answer is more speculative than reasonably factual.

Comment: @Fizz Nuclear weapons in space would be easier to detect than in land or sea. And yes, the US would have to provide proof to the international community that the Russians have placed WMDs in space, to gain support for strong sanctions against it. But there's also the factor that such weapons are first-strike weapons, and as per the MAD theory, Russia would likely announce it to the world. After all, the whole point of MAD strategy is posturing about your capability to destroy your rival.

Comment: "Nuclear weapons in space would be easier to detect than in land or sea." And you're basing that on what? Remember all the [cold war] hooha about the Buran or the Space Shuttle potentially carrying nukes? Nobody thought that detecting their payload was easy then, AFAICR.

Comment: And the Soviet military space stations were also claimed/camouflaged as civilian ones during the cold war. They didn't even admit firing that cannon you've pictured in space [it happened in 1975] until after the cold war (1) had ended https://www.popularmechanics.com/military/weapons/a18187/here-is-the-soviet-unions-secret-space-cannon/

Comment: Here's a link/story about the Soviet belief that Space Shuttle would carry nukes, and what they did in response, since you've apparently never heard of that https://www.thespacereview.com/article/3855/1

Comment: And here's a relevant quote from that "The [Soviet] report concluded that an American space shuttle, launched from Vandenberg Air Force Base in California and flying from south to north over the Soviet Union, could make a “dive” in its orbit as it passed over Moscow, and release a nuclear weapon. This technique would enable a weapon to be deployed from the shuttle and detonate over Moscow 200 seconds later, far faster than an American submarine-launched ballistic missile could accomplish the same task."

Comment: Etc. https://books.google.com/books?id=3QY-4UKu-qUC&pg=PA70

Comment: @Fizz I may have overestimated how hard it is to detect nuclear weapons in space - I based this on a recent reading of how particle beams are being used in ABM systems. Still if the US claims that RU has launched WMD into space the onus is on them to prove it. Note also that we have come a long way from the cold war where both parties did a lot of nuclear weapon testing, even in space, in secret. So RU also doesn't gain anything by hiding it as per MAD. Short of ending the war, I have outlined all the things that US can offer to RU to entice them. "Sticks" options are indeed limited here.

Comment: As for your asides, you may excused for reading that in Wired, but [it looks like](https://rollcall.com/2024/02/14/house-delays-plans-on-surveillance-program-reauthorization-vote/) the so-called section 702 proposed reforms are just a joke, at best pandering to Jim Jordan and the like, e.g. notifying the House if the FBI does a search for any of its members. Outside groups say that's hardly any reform.

Comment: As for the "hype" being related/motivated to/by Ukraine, that's also pretty doubtful, as news from the front speaks for itself far more clearly https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-68323366

Comment: @Fizz Doesnt the fact that UA is strategically withdrawing suggests it's desperation for US aid? And I was [quoting the Russians](https://www.reuters.com/world/kremlin-dismisses-us-warning-about-russian-nuclear-capability-space-2024-02-15/) - The Kremlin dismissed on Thursday a warning by the United States about Moscow's new nuclear capabilities in space, calling it a "malicious fabrication" and a trick by the White House aimed at getting U.S. lawmakers to approve more money to counter Russia - which makes sense. Nobody sane would believe the propaganda that Republicans love RU more than US.

Comment: You have missed another "stick."  The United States can adopt the doctrine that a launch of such a satellite, by any country, would be an act of war against every other country (including the US).  Because this would be putting a nuclear missile in space, it can be treated as a launch of a nuclear missile with an unknown destination.  Now giving a country an ultimatum not to "attack" the United States would be quite a stick.

Comment: @wrod: I see you've written nearly the same thing/answer under my Q, and so you've declared it a "push" question. But the thing is, AFAIK, the US *hasn't* publicly made such a statement yet, i.e. "if someone launches a nuke in orbit, we'll consider it an act of war against us."

Comment: @wrod: at best some *former* US officials have [declared](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-13087485/cia-leon-panetta-russia-nuclear-space-weapon.html) that *detonating* a nuke in space that *takes out a US satellite* would/should be considered an act of war. Which is a rather higher threshold.

Comment: @fizz what i wrote was that saying that preventing such a launch would be amount to starting WW3, which is completely unnecessary for the interrogatory part of the question.  It whitewashes the blame for such a potential act by blaming a potential defender (the one preventing the launch) instead of the perpetrator (the one launching a nuclear missile).  Both the question and this answer seem to miss the point that launching a nuclear missile is itself effectively an act of war.  No US officials are commenting on this possibility because no one is seriously considering it a possibility.

Comment: @wrod You make a good argument - when the US moved nuclear missiles into Italy and Turkey, nearer to Russia, and Russia threatened to place its nuclear missiles to Cuba, both countries showed a "panic" response, and came to the brink of a war till sanity prevailed and both parties agreed to withdraw their missiles. So yes, an orbital nuclear platform in space capable of launching such nuclear weapons can be considered similar to the Turkey-Cuba missile crisis. Note though that the whole point of this question is to *avoid* a military conflict. So threatening one is not an option at all.

Comment: @sfxedit i get that the point is to avoid a conflict, but I don't see how issuing an ultimatum to avoid this particular form of an escalation would detract from that goal.